# Audio alerts or pop ups with geth

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

Is it possible to play an audio alert inside of geth or make a pop up alert? I know you can make a system beep with `console.log(“\007”)` but I want something a little less generic because this is the same sound my computer makes when I press the down arrow on terminal for instance.